# Java applet works on Oracle JRE 7u5, doesn't work on 7u6

Tags: java, applet, classloader, java-7

Our team has an applet that is working fine in Oracle JRE 7u5.  Upon updating the JRE to 7u6 or 7u7, the applet fails to initialize.  An exception is thrown by the class loader during its loading of the log4j classes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.class$(PropertyConfigurator.java:572)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:752)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
```

Has anyone else observed this behavior?

Comment: Go to the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) & follow the instructions..

Comment: Found it, thanks.  The bug has already been reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular bug has been observed by others and has been filed in Oracle's [bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7194301).